# Ideal MHD energy transfer

Tags: conservation-laws, magnetohydrodynamics

Consider ideal MHD: infinite conductivity, frozen-in magnetic field lines etc. Clearly total energy of the system is conserved (magnetic field energy + plasma internal energy + kinetic energy = const). This suggests that the energy can be redistributed between these components, for example kinetic energy can be converted into magnetic.

But I don't understand how is it going on the microscopic level. Lorentz force does not do work and because of perfect conductivity **E** = -**v**$\times$**B**, electric field is perpendicular to velocity so again zero work. Naively it looks like magnetic energy should be conserved separately. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well you've got a fluid, so don't look at the microscopic level! The magnetic pressure straightens out curved flows; cf. [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/108358/25301).